# Add specific information to specific column in pandas out of shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas variables :

df1:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [time_tweet, time_stock, sentiment, trend]
Index: []
```

df2:

```
                      index   likes    ...      user_screen_name  sentiment
created_at                            ...                                 
2019-02-27 05:36:29      0   94574    ...       realDonaldTrump   positive
2019-02-27 05:31:21      1   61666    ...       realDonaldTrump   negative
2019-02-26 18:08:14      2  151844    ...       realDonaldTrump   positive
2019-02-26 04:50:37      3  184597    ...       realDonaldTrump   positive
2019-02-26 04:50:36      4  181641    ...       realDonaldTrump   negative
2019-02-26 03:04:49      5  104291    ...       realDonaldTrump   negative
2019-02-25 23:17:02      6  104043    ...       realDonaldTrump   positive
2019-02-25 23:12:25      7   74302    ...       realDonaldTrump   positive
```

df1.shape:

```
(0, 4)
```

df2.shape:

```
(591, 10)
```

The aim of this code is to create a loop that will go through every information in df2. When a specific condition will be true, the specific information from df2 will be add at the end of a specific column to df1.

For example:

```
for row in range(0,519):
    if "specific condition" :
        df1.time_tweet.loc[-1]=df2.like[row]
        df1.time_stock.loc[-1]=df2.sentiment[row]
        ...
```

The actual problem is that when I execute the command :

```
print(df1)
```

It shows me an empty dataset.

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can change how you add data. Use the `.loc` operator to index into the DataFrame.

E.g.

```
df1.loc[index_loop, "col_1"]= df2.information[index_loop]
```

this will add new rows if they do not exist yet.

**Update**
You are almost there. The dataframe is empty because `df1.time_stock` will return a *copy* of the data which you then insert into.

Change the insertions to

```
df1.loc[-1,"time_tweet"] = df2.like[row]
df1.loc[-1,"time_stock"] = df2.sentiment[row]
```

and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you a lot! but will it work if I have for example 1000 information to add and the dimension of df1 is (0,4)?

Comment: @stefan Depends on what you mean. Does `df2.information[index_loop]` contain more than one value? If yes, is it always the same amount of values? Do you want to expand the columns dynamically as well?

If there is only one value you want to insert in a particular column, then yes this will work just fine.

Comment: Yes obviously more than one value otherwise I would be not out of the dimension of df1 as I mentioned in the description. I don't want to expand the column, I want to expend the rows (sorry for not enough details)

Comment: @stefan I think you misunderstand the error messages and my question. If you add a bit more information to the question with expected input and output I can update the answer for you.